# $AG,AF$ are perpendiculars to the internal bisectors $CG,BF$ and $GF$ extended intersects $AB,AC$ at $H,I$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

In the figure $AG,AF$ are perpendiculars to the internal bisectors $CG,BF$ and GF extended  intersects $AB,AC$ at $H,I$ respectively.Find $5GF-HI$ if $c=AB=7,a=BC=8,b=CA=5$ [image]

I know we can calculate the internal bisectors length by stewarts formula as $$BD=\frac{2\sqrt{s(s-b)}}{a+c}$$ And similarly for the other  bisector.From here we can also calculate $AF,AG$.I am stuck otherwise..it  looks like $GF$ is parallel to $BC$ but  i cant prove it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend $AF$ and $AG$ until it touches $BC$.

[image]

Since $CG, BF$ bisects $\angle ACB$ and $\angle ABC$, and $AF \perp BF$, $AG \perp GC$:

$\triangle AGC \cong \triangle G'GC$ and $\triangle AFB \cong \triangle F'FB$ by considering common sides and AAS.

Hence $BF'=7, CG'= 5$ and $F,G$ are midpoints of $AF', AG'$ respectively.

By midpoint/midline theorem, $FG // F'G'$ and $FG = \frac12 F'G' = \frac12(8-(8-7)-(8-5))=2$.

By considering the parallel lines, similar triangles and using midpoint/midline theorem again, we see that $HI$ is also half of $BC$, giving $HI = 4$. Therefore $5GF - HI =6$.