# A problem on Angle bisectors of a triangle and perpendiculars.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

1. From $A$ perpendiculars $AX, AY$ are drawn to the bisectors of the exterior angles of $B$ and $C$ of $\Delta ABC$. Prove that $XY || BC$.
2. Prove that the feet of the four perpendiculars dropped from a vertex of a triangle upon the four bisectors of the other two angle are collinear.
3. In triangle $\Delta ABC, X $and $Y$ be the feet of perpendiculars from vertex $A$ to the internal angle bisector of $∠B$ and $∠C$ respectively. Line $XY$ meets $AB$ at $P$ and $AC$ at $Q$. If $AB = 7$ cm, $BC = 8$ cm and $CA = 5$ cm then find $PQ$ and $XY$.

These were 3 questions with almost similar configurations; as I wasn't able to solve the first one, I couldn't solve the next two either (I don't know if it's just psychological or something but anyway).

So, could someone please provide the **SOLUTION for the first one and just hints for the next two**

A solution using just elementary geometry would be ideal but any solution would be really helpful,

Thanks[image]

Comment: Hint : 1. Draw internal angle bisectors and do angle chasing. 2. 3. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916954/ag-af-are-perpendiculars-to-the-internal-bisectors-cg-bf-and-gf-extended-i/3916985#3916985

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$AG,AF$ are perpendiculars to the internal bisectors $CG,BF$ and $GF$ extended intersects $AB,AC$ at $H,I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916954/ag-af-are-perpendiculars-to-the-internal-bisectors-cg-bf-and-gf-extended-i)

Comment: Construct the parallel to $BC$ through $A$: $AX$ and $AY$ are then angle bisectors.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca how would i proceed after that? As we don't know most of the lengths or ratios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice solution using trigonometry; I will name the points according to your diagram (i.e., using $AD$ and $AE$ instead of $AX$ and $AY$). So let $F$ and $G$ be the feet of the perpendiculars from $D$ and $E$ onto $BC$, respectively. It suffices to show that $d(BC, D)=|DF|=|EG|=d(BC, E)$.

Notice that $\Delta DGB$ and $\Delta ADB$ are similar and hence

$$\frac{|DF|}{|AD|}=\frac{|DB|}{|AB|}\Leftrightarrow |DF|=\frac{|AD||DB|}{|AB|}$$

However, using $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ to denote the interior angles of the triangle, as usual, we have $|AD|=|AB|\cos(\beta/2)$ and $|DB|=|AB|\sin(\beta/2)$, so

$$|DF|=|AB|\sin(\beta/2)\cos(\beta/2)=\frac{1}{2}|AB|\sin(\beta)$$

Finally, the sine rule in $\Delta ABC$ then gives

$$|DF|=\frac{1}{2}|BC|\frac{\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)}{\sin(\alpha)}$$

and by symmetry, the same argument for $E$ instead of $D$ gives

$$|EG|=\frac{1}{2}|BC|\frac{\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)}{\sin(\alpha)}$$

and we are done.

For problem 2, call the feet onto the internal bisectors $H$ and $I$. Then a similar computation should give exactly the same values for $d(H, BC)$ and $d(I, BC)$ as above and you are done.

For problem 3, use that the length of the altitude from $A$ in $\Delta ABC$ is given by $|BC|\frac{\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)}{\sin(\alpha)}$.

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much for this; i can't tell you how much i appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The dashed lines are angle bisectors. Using angle chasing, congruency and mid-point theorem, bunch of isosceles triangles and various lengths can be found. I'll leave the work to you.

$RS$ contains the midpoints of $AB, AC$. The final results should be :

$$RS = \dfrac{1}{2}A_3A_4 = s$$

$$PQ = \dfrac{1}{2}A_1A_2 = \dfrac{1}{2}(CA_2+BA_1 - BC) = s-a$$